# How do I deploy a Railo project to AWS using Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, deployment, amazon-web-services, railo

I'm running a [Railo](http://getrailo.org) project on my local Ubuntu box, Eclipse Indigo, Tomcat 7, Fusebox 4 and AWS Toolkit for Eclipse

I have my project running smoothly on my local dev box. Trying to deploy the project at times takes under 10min (very rare) and other times it never happens, just have the loading bar showing and/or eventually fails.

I've tried publishing a new project which works at times, but when trying to do incremental deployment it just almost never happens (it worked once). In fact after the one time when I deployed the project I've not been able to do it again.

> Unable to upload application to Amazon S3: Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /home/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/aws-eclipse-1365821331354619151.war (No such file or directory)
>   Unable to calculate MD5 hash: /home/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.wst.server.core/tmp1/aws-eclipse-1365821331354619151.war (No such file or directory)

Rightly so, there is no such file in that location. But why? Is it a permissions issue? I gave myself root right for GUI file browser but still no joy (gksu nautilus).

I'm new to AWS and Ubuntu environment and not sure what i should do in order to deploy.

Comment: David, this appears to be two distinct questions - so it should be asked as two questions - i.e. you should split the second problem into its own question. Clear, focused questions are more likely to get help than rambling ones.

Comment: fair point Peter, i suppose i rambling due to frustration!!! I hope this is more clear and to the point

Comment: Don't worry, I know exactly how it feels! A lot of my questions start as frustrated rambling, but I always try to read them back and rewrite more precise versions. Can takes multiple rewrites to get there, but also there are times when the act of re-framing the question helps me figure out an answer on my own.

Comment: Unfortunately I know nothing about AWS so can't directly help, but I notice there's an [AWS Toolkit for Eclipse](http://aws.amazon.com/eclipse/) - if that's something you're using, maybe adding it to your question/title will attract more attention; otherwise, it's something new to try? :)

Answer (score 2):

So one of your questions seems to be problems in uploading files to S3 via the AWS java SDK right?..  on line  1011 https://github.com/amazonwebservices/aws-sdk-for-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.java#L1011

So what I think your doing here is trying to execute a putObject S3 command which had a Content-MD5 hash saying the request could not be authenticated. I had this issue I found out that the MD5 hash needs to be base64 encoded and is required by Amazon to upload files.

However, looking at your error "No such file or directory" this could be a different issue. Doing a quick Google I found a post that could be of interest...

https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=143497

Hope some of this helps.

Comment: thanks for your reply Glyn, unfortunately that didnt work for me, i've tried many different solutions and have come to a dead end. I think it time i went back to just uploading to a virtual server rather than wasting my time with aws. If anyone has any ideas pls post it as im still interested to try something new.

Comment: if its just deployment this is the method I use so easy... http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N-v_DBFbZxo Deploying to EC2 using Git